# Как организовать условие цикла while из двух параллельных запросов?

Tags: while, php, mysql

Есть 2 запроса к БД:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) //первый запрос
$rw = mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt) // второй запрос
```

В настоящий момент для того, чтобы закрутить их в одном цикле, я применил следующую конструкцию:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $rw = mysql_fetch_assoc($rslt);?>
        //первое объявление
        <td id="bllt_date_cont" class="auto_date">
           <?php echo $rw['date']?>
        </td>

        //второе объявление
        <td id="bllt_date_cont" class="auto_date">
    <?php echo $row['date']?>
    </td>
    <?php}
```

Но эта конструкция не позволяет мне отсортировать результаты по дате. Вернее, они отсортированы, но каждый запрос, естественно, делает это независимо. Как их отсортировать в цикле так, чтобы они еще и согласовывались друг с другом?

Вот код запроса к БД:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,rub,cntr,marka,model...author_id,pic
                        FROM auto
                        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $col,20");

$rslt = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,text,sostoyanie,price...srok,year
                        FROM bullet
                        WHERE podrubs='103'
                        OR podrubs='104'
                        OR podrubs='105'
                        OR podrubs='106'
                        OR podrubs='107'
                        OR podrubs='108'
                        OR podrubs='109'
                        OR podrubs='110'
                        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $col,20");
```

Comment: Может, получить все данные в одном запросе к БД, в уже отсортированном виде?

Comment: Напишите какие запросы используются. Возможно получится сделать всё в одном.

Comment: написал. как видите, строки в таблицах различны по названиям, если это существенно и важно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете решить это одним запросом вида:

```
SELECT id, date, rub, ..., null title, ... 
FROM auto

UNION

SELECT id, date, null rub, ..., title, ... 
FROM bullet 
WHERE prodrubs in ('104', '105', ...)

ORDER BY date desc, id desc
```

Comment: понял. буду делать сейчас. есть вопрос: а какую функцию выполняется null в перечислении строк? что оно дает?

Comment: если в одной таблице есть поле, которого нет во второй, мы можем добавить его во вторую таблицу с пустым значением null, в каждом из объединяемых селектов должен быть одинаковый набор полей, идущих в одном и том же порядке

Comment: спасибо! все предельно понятно.